# Splitting String with ".split" but keep delimeters (a string) in match array

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have this string

```
"name={{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}lastName={{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}street[696]{{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}OK
```

that I'd like to have back into this array:

```
['name={{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}', 'lastName={{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}', 'street[696]{{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}', 'OK']
```

I tried with this:

```
String[] tokens = buffer.split("(?<=[a-zA-Z]+)");
```

but looks like the jvm got stuck!

any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex for splitting:

```
(?!^)(?=\\b[a-zA-Z])
```

This regex means split when not at start and when there is a letter following word boundary.

**Code:**

```
String s="name={{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}lastName={{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}street[696]{{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}OK";
String[] toks = s.split( "(?!^)(?=\\b[a-zA-Z])" );
for (String tok: toks)
    System.out.printf("[%s]%n", tok);
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
[name={{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}]
[lastName={{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}]
[street[696]{{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}]
[OK]
```

Comment: I have a similar problem .. the "name", "lastName" tokens might be a number internally:
String s="na2me={{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}las43tName={{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}street[696]{{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}OK";
I'd like the same results ... 
I tried this without success:
String[] tokens = buffer.split("(?!^)(?=\\b\\w\\d+)");

Comment: yes, sorry ... forgot to say without curly bracket:
String s="na2me=1233456456las43tName=89763456street=653563456OK";

Comment: This string looks very different from what you have in question with `{{` and `}}`. Try: `String[] toks = s.split( "(?<=\\d)(?=[a-zA-Z])" );`

Comment: yes, you're right; maybe worth to create another question!
btw, your solution doesn't work.

Comment: Yes difficult to understand a question from comments, pls create a new one with your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

//try this

String x = "name={{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}lastName={{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}street[696]{{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}OK";

```
    String[] arr = x.split("}}");


    for(int i=0;i<arr.length-1;i++){
        arr[i]+="}";
    }

    //display
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
```